# how to control multiple buttons in one time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

i am a beginner ios developer and i am making  **TIC TAC TOE**

i want to make an array to control all the buttons i one time instead of writing alot of code

so how can i link all 9 buttons in one array ?

instead of writing

`button1 , button2 , button 3 ,button4 >> button [x]`

or some thing like this

pleeeeease i am beginner so accept my question if it is stupid and dont rate down

or tell me where is the answer and i'll delete my question

thaaanks for your helping  : - )

Comment: Create an array of `UIButton *`?  What's the complexity?

Comment: Or even better, use `IBOutletCollection` if you are using `storyboard` for your buttons.

Comment: Something like: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection (UIButton) NSArray * buttons`

Comment: @trojanfoe maybe i tried before and it didnt success but i will try now 

thanks :)

Comment: @Desdenova, for the `IBoutletCollection` you don't need to use the _storyboard_ it can work with standard `xib` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access UIButton by it's **TAG**.

Give different **TAG** to each `UIButton`

For example

```
for (int i = 1; i <=9; i++) {
        
        UIButton *button =(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        
    }
```